# MySQL Update joining information from another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, sql-update

Im really new at MySQL so please I hope you can help me since I couldn't find any related answer to my problem anywhere. 
Im trying to update a field in a MySQL table with information thats in another table, so far I have something like this:

```
UPDATE item i 
SET i.brandId = (SELECT t.taxonomyId 
                 FROM taxonomy t 
                 WHERE t.taxonomyName = (SELECT b.brandName 
                                         FROM brand b 
                                         WHERE b.brandId = i.brandId 
                                         AND b.companyId = 9) 
                 AND t.taxonomyType = 'brand' 
                 AND t.companyId = 9) 
WHERE i.companyId = 9
```

Basically I have an old table called `brand` and copied all its information to a new table called `taxonomy`, the only difference between both tables is the ID (everything else keeps the same), so I need to update all the `brandId` fields in the table `item` from `brand` to `taxonomy` so I can preserve the names updating the IDs.

The problem with my query is I get an error saying: Subquery returns more than 1 row

Thanks!

EDIT:

The tables structures are:

```
brand
brandId - brandName - companyId

item
itemId - itemName - brandId - companyId

taxonomy
taxonomyId - taxonomyName - companyId
```

Comment: Do a select * using the select statement in your update (change the select t.taxonomyid to select *), why is more than 1 row coming back? Where do the columns differ? When you figure that out you should be able to fix the query.

Comment: Is there a way I can replace the UPDATE with a SELECT so I can see what is returned without updating the table?

Comment: Yeah, take the select query out of the update (take everything enclosed in the () and run it (just the select statement), but like I said do a select * so that you can see what column values are repeated vs. not repeated

Comment: Take a look at my answer below but I think you might have a problem in that either in BRAND or TAXONOMY a (TAXONOMYNAME and COMPANYID) or (BRANDNAME and COMPANYID) combination has 2+ unique IDs. Are there any constraints on these tables?

Comment: `since I couldn't find any related answer to my problem anywhere.` That's hard to imagine since I found hundreds of related questions and answers just here at SO for that error in MySQL. I can't imagine how many hits I'd get if I searched the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want this query:

```
update item i
   set i.brandid =
       (select t.taxonomyid
          from taxonomy t
          join brand b
            on t.taxonomyname = b.brandname
           and t.companyid = b.companyid
         where b.brandid = i.brandid)
```

To test before doing the update, try running the following which will illustrate what will get changed:

```
select t.taxonomyid   as new_id_to_be_given,
       b.brandid      as old_id_going_away,
       t.taxonomyname,
       t.companyid
  from taxonomy t
  join brand b
    on t.taxonomyname = b.brandname
   and t.companyid = b.companyid
 order by 1
```

This will replace the brandid on the item table with the taxonomyid value associated with the same (taxonomyname and brandname) and (companyid and companyid) values between the 2 tables.

If this query STILL returns 2+ rows, that means the TAXONOMY or BRAND table has more than one row for a unique combination of taxonomyname and companyid.

To diagnose where this might be happening you can run the following (and then after resolving the issues, you can run the above):

```
select 'taxonomy' as table_with_issue,
       taxonomyname,
       companyid,
       group_concat(taxonomyid separator ', ') as multiple_ids
  from taxonomy
 group by taxonomyname, companyid
having count(*) > 1
union all
select 'brand', brandname, brandid, group_concat(brandid separator ', ')
  from brand
 group by brandname, brandid
having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Subquery returns more than 1 row means that either of the Select statements returns more than one row.

You cannot set i.brandId to more than one value.  One thing you could *try* would be adding limit 1:

```
UPDATE item i 
SET i.brandId = (SELECT t.taxonomyId 
                 FROM taxonomy t 
                 WHERE t.taxonomyName = (SELECT distinct b.brandName 
                                         FROM brand b 
                                         WHERE b.brandId = i.brandId 
                                         AND b.companyId = 9 limit 1) 
                 AND t.taxonomyType = 'brand' 
                 AND t.companyId = 9 limit 1) 
WHERE i.companyId = 9
```

but I would try to figure out how to add something to the where clause to make sure that you are returning only one row.

Comment: This could be dangerous if he doesn't know why the query is returning more than one row. Who is to say he wants to update it with the first one returned?

Comment: Agreed.  At least this will get him/her on the right path but at least he or she could see what is being returned then assigned by the update.  We don't know what the structure and data look like--no schema was posted.

Comment: Hi thanks, for your answers, I tried to avoid the LIMIT 1 because there should not be more than one record in the first place, so I don't want to update more than 10000 records with the wrong values. For the structure see the updated question